# Dependent Dropdown Contents with jquery-select2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, jquery-select2

I have a Rails 4 app where I'm using Jquery-select2 for my dropdown lists. I have two dropdowns where I want the selection in the first do dictate what the user can select in the second. Sort of like selecting a country and being given a list of states for that country.

In my application I have Demographic and Response models. When someone selects a Demographic I want to populate the Responses list with the appropriate items for that Demographic.

I had this working before I started using Select2. But, I'm missing some of the nuances in how to get it working with Select2. I'm so so with Rails but Javascript and Jquery are my weak points.

Here is my form:

```
<form>
      <%= f.label :demographic %><br>
      <%= select_tag "demographics", options_from_collection_for_select(@demographic, "id", "demographic_name"), id: "simple-example" %></br></br>
      <%= f.label :operator %><br>
      <%= select_tag "operators", options_from_collection_for_select(@operator, "id", "name"), id: "operator" %></br></br>
      <%= f.label :response %><br>
      <%= select_tag "responses", options_from_collection_for_select(@response, "id", "name"), id: "response" %></br></br>
      <%= f.label :operator_selection %><br>
      <%= select_tag "operator_selections", options_from_collection_for_select(@operator_selection, "id", "name"), id: "operator_selection" %></br></br>
    </form>
```

Here is some CoffeeScript which I found and modified and had working prior to Select2:

```
jQuery ->
  responses = $('#query_response_id').html()
  $('#query_demographic_id').change ->
    demographic = $('#query_demographic_id :selected').text()
    escaped_demographic = demographic.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
    options = $(responses).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_demographic}']").html()
    if options
      $('#query_response_id').html(options)
      $('#query_response_id').parent().show()
    else
      $('#query_response_id').empty()
      $('#query_response_id').parent().hide()
```

The line of code I used before Select2 for the Response model dropdown was:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :response_id, Demographic.order(:demographic_name), :responses, :demographic_name, :id, :name, include_blank: :true %>
```

When I look at that it appears that somehow I need to move `:responses, :demographic_name,` into this line:

```
<%= select_tag "responses", options_from_collection_for_select(@response, "id", "name"), id: "response" %>
```

But, everything I've tried has failed. I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106176/dynamic-dependent-dropdown-with-jquery-select2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797261/select2-dependent-dropdown-lists) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691214/handsontable-select2-dependent-dropdowns), but none of them are Rails related so I'm stuck.

Any ideas?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a rails guy but there are bunch of things you need to check ,  1. demographic = $('#query_demographic_id :selected').text() ---> this should be $('#query_demographic_id option:selected').text(), 2.  optgroup[label='#{escaped_demographic}']") -- Here you are targetting the element with label having ID = #{escaped_demographic}, since ID is unique in DOM, you can simply do : $("'#{escaped_demographic}']").html()

Comment: I made these changes, but, they didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Quick question before I answer:

Roughly how many options are there going to be in both the Demographic and Response drop downs?

It seems to me that you could either load the Response drop down over Ajax based on the selected Demographic. I would use this approach if there are more than say 50 total responses.

But if there are less, I would use jQuery to filter the second drop down.

I can help you with either approach. Let me know

Comment: Probably about 300 Demographic items and potentially thousands of responses.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30244576/359284). If that doesn't help, I might be able to write up a situation-specific answer later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with the simplest case: First of all, just get the form working without Select2 or Chosen, or whatever. Just use basic Select drop downs, so you can see what's happening.

In your situation, you can load all the Demographics up, and create an empty select for the Responses:

```
<%= form_tag("/test") do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag "demographic", options_from_collection_for_select(@demographic, "id", "name"), id: "demographic", class: "chosen" %><br>
  <%= select_tag "responses", "", id: "responses", class: "chosen" %>
<% end %>
```

Then when the selected Demographic changes, you can update the options for the Responses over ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Listen for the demographic changing
  $('#demographic').change(function(){

    // Grab the id of currenly selected demographic
    var demographic_id = $(this).val();

    // Query the responses for this demographic:
    $.get( "/responses.json", { demographic_id: demographic_id }, function( data ) {

      // Remove the existing options in the responses drop down:
      $("#responses").html("");

      // Loop over the json and populate the Responses options:
      $.each( data, function( index, value ) {
        $("#responses").append( "<option value='" + value.id + "'>" + value.name + "</option>" );
      });

    });
  });

});
```

Finally, you'll just need an index action on the **ResponsesController** to give you the json for the select box. You need JSON in the following format.

```
[{"id":2,"name":"Direct Request - Telecommunication"},{"id":3,"name":"Direct Request - Internet/Electronic"},{"id":4,"name":"Company Request - Written"}]
```

This action should give you something like it:

```
class ResponsesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @responses = Response.order(:name)
    @responses = @responses.where(demographic_id: params[:demographic_id]) if params[:demographic_id].present?

    # You don't need this respond to block if you have a jbuilder view set up at app/views/responses/index.json.jbuilder
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @responses }
    end
  end

end
```

Now when your Demographic changes in the first select, you should get a filtered list of Responses in the second select. If this is working, you can now add the JQuery plugin of your choice. Personally, I prefer [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to Select2.

To get chosen working in the above case, you just need to modify the Javascript slightly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Attach the chosen behaviour to all selects with a class of "chosen"
  $('.chosen').chosen();

  $('#demographic').change(function(){
    var selected_demographic = $(this).val();

    // Query the responses for this demographic:
    $.get( "/responses.json", { demographic_id: selected_demographic }, function( data ) {

      // Remove the existing options in the responses drop down:
      $("#responses").html("");

      // Loop over the new response json and populate the select list:
      $.each( data, function( index, value ) {
        $("#responses").append( "<option value='" + value.id + "'>" + value.name + "</option>" );
      });

      // Now reset chosen, with the new options:
      $("#responses").trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: I'm not 100% committed to Select2. Let me try putting this in via Chosen.

Comment: I've made all of these changes and am getting a 'undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass" message on `<%= select_tag "demographics", options_from_collection_for_select(@demographics, "id", "demographic_name"), id: "demographics", class: "chosen" %>`

Comment: Ok, I got the form displaying. I had to make one minor tweak changing "@demographics" to "@demographic" and it rendered. However, it's not picking up the CSS for formatting and selecting a demographic doesn't populate the responses dropdown. I have the appropriate css and js files in the asset pipeline directories and have recompiled my assets. I also tried explicitly stating the chosen files be included in application.js and application.css.

Comment: Moved javascript to the head of the template and the CSS is rendering now. Still no luck getting the responses dropdown populated.

Comment: Is your JSON rendering properly, if you go to localhost:3000/responses.json ?
Also, when you change demographic, is the AJAX call working? Take a look in the rails server output to see if the GET is working...

Comment: Found a typo "repond" should have been "respond" once I put that in and load localhost:3000/responses.json the page simply shows []. When I load the form with the dropdowns the responses dropdown is populated, but it's filled with items like this `<li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">[object Object]</li>` "object Object" looks like it's having problems pulling in the "Name" field. Otherwise the counts look correct.

Comment: After selecting an item in the demographics list here is what the server is showing `Started GET "/responses.json?demographic_id=157" for ::1 at 2015-11-16 23:22:53 -0600
Processing by ResponsesController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"demographic_id"=>"157"}
  Response Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "responses".* FROM "responses" WHERE "responses"."demographic_id" = $1  [["demographic_id", 157]]
  Rendered responses/index.json.jbuilder (6.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 34ms (Views: 16.6ms | ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)`

Comment: I have updated my answer.
The code I shared previously was not tested at all. But I have since got it working. Two things were needed:
1) I had the $.each loop coded wrongly, so it was not populating the drop down correctly.
2) The render json line in the ResponsesController needed to be tweaked to render out the json properly. Mind you, I can see you are using jbuilder, so perhaps you are rendering it out differently anyway.
Let me know if the above works better.

Comment: Ok, we're getting closer, but it's still not working for me. I really appreciate your effort on this. The mix of JS/Jquery/AJAX is an area I need to beef up on. The responses list is now definitely populating with something (and resizing itself when I select a demographic. When I run localhost:3000/responses.json I'm now getting a lot of output. But, the responses are all filled with `<option value="undefined">undefined</option>`. I've tried putting the controller code both inside "index" and at the same level as "index"

Comment: Your problem is with this loop:

$.each( data, function( index, value ) {
        $("#responses").append( "<option value='" + value[0] + "'>" + value[1] + "</option>" );
      });

The Javascript is not reading the JSON correctly. Within the .each loop try using:

console.log(value);

To output the object. Are you using Chrome? It's the easiest way to see what your JS is getting. Also, could you post the raw output of localhost:3000/responses.json for me. I might be able to debug it for you. Also do console.log(data); before the $.each

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95362/discussion-between-scott-s-and-rlarcombe).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know rails, 
but i used Javasctipt/Jquery, Bootstrap.

Is this solve your problem.

I binding country and state values from Javascript Array.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4ad7A/316/

```
    <script>
   $("#country, #state").select2();populateCountries("country", "state");
   </script>
```